# Access .ldb file with python

Tags: python, database

Is it possible to access `.ldb` file with python? The closest I can find is [package `pyodbc`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-Microsoft-Access) and it seems that only `.mbd` is supported there.

Is it possible to convert from `.ldb` to `.mbd`? (I don't have software with which I can open `.lbd`.)

(The `.ldb` files are downloaded when downloading the Ethereum blockchain.)

Comment: Have you looked at  https://plyvel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ yet?

Comment: The "l" in "ldb" seems to mean "locked" (https://fileinfo.com/extension/ldb) instead of "level". I am not sure whether the package you mentioned is relevant.

Comment: did you figure it out?